# Paris CDG layover requirement

Tags: international-travel

I’m traveling from Jeddah, Saudi Arabia to Indianapolis and have a 6hr layover in Paris, I have a US visitor visa and was wondering if there’s anything else I would need if I’m stopping in CDG.

thanks !

Comment: Maybe a MasterCard/Visa credit card, to buy something to eat while you wait to change planes? Is there something in particular you wish to know about?

Comment: Or a few Euros...

Comment: @MichaelHampton visitors from some countries require a visa even if only transiting in CDG.